# how to pass a request while page is redirect with another page using asp.net api using angular js front end

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('myApp2', []);
app.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, $http,$window)
{
    $scope.getLogdetails = function (postCredential) {

        //alert("hello check data");
        $http({
            method: 'Post',
            url:'https://localhost:44339/Signs/datacheck',
            data: $scope.postdata,
            params: { username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password }
        }).then(function mysucess(response) {
            console.log(response, "response");
            if (response.data =="true")
            {
                //console.log("save")
                //console.log(response.data,"sar");

                window.location = '/homepage.html?username=' + name;
                //console.log(response.data,"");

            } else {
                alert("username name passords incorect");
            }

        })
    }
});
```

this my js file 
                    .
getting this error as in the screen[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iq2e.png)shot

[image]

Comment: Please avoid using images of text. Instead copy or type out the text into the question editor and format appropriately. Images of error messages are not searchable, nor are they accessible.

Comment: The error in your linked image says username is undefined. Could you hard code your username and see? Like `params: { username: 'testuser', password: 'password' }`

Comment: It is really a bad practice to send a password as a URL parameter.